# How to Upload Large files in Javascript in a Single Connection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, networking, file-upload

I am trying to write some HTML/JS code which will facilitate uploading large files (multi-GB) to a remote server.  Previously we had been using a flash uploader which uploaded a given file in a single network request.  The flash would open a network connection, read a chunk of a file into memory then write that chunk to the network connection then grab the next chunk then write to the network etc. etc. until the entire file is uploaded.  It was done this way because most web browsers will attempt to read an entire file into memory before attempting to upload.  When dealing with multi-GB files, this essentially crashes the client system because it uses all of the client memory.  Now we are having issues with using flash, so it needs to go, we want to replace it without needing to modify the existing server-side code.

A few google searches for jquery uploaders reveals that there are plenty of libraries which support "chunking" but they "chunk" over multiple requests.  We do not want to chunk a file over multiple network requests, we merely want the JS to read the file in chunks as it writes the file to a single network connection.

Anybody know a library which can do this out of the box?

We are not opposed to modifying an existing library if need be.  Anyone have a snippet that resembles the bellow pseudo-code that I may be able to retrofit into a library?

```
connection = fopen(...);
fputs("123", connection);
... some unrelated code ...
fputs("456", connection);
fclose(connection);
```

(excuse my use of C functions in pseudo JS code ... I know that is not how you do it in JS, I am merely demonstrating at a low-level the flow for how I want to write to the network connection before closing it)

NOTE: We are not trying to "modernize" or improve this project extensively -- we are not trying to re-do this project. We have some old code that has sat here for years and we want to make as few changes to the server-side code as possible. I have more important projects to modernize and make more efficient -- this one we just need to work. Please don't advise me to impliment "proper" file chunking on the server side -- that was my suggestion, and if my suggestion were taken then that task would have been assigned to a different developer.  Out of my control now, this is a client-side-only fix please!

Thanks, sorry for any headache!

Comment: If you want one single connection, try using web socket and transfer the chunks

Answer (score 0):

You could try [binaryjs](https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs). I haven't looked into the internals but I know it supports manually setting the chunk size. Maybe you can even set it to Infinity.

Specifically you could try:

```
var client = new BinaryClient('example.com', { chunkSize: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY });
client.send('data...');
```

Note: binaryjs is a NodeJS server library, and a browser-compatible client library.